# Rendering bug in long community list in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

1. Tap *All n communities* in user profile
2. Scroll down (i.e. swipe up)
3. Select any site
4. Go back to the community list with tapping `<`
5. It is already scrolled and...moved.

[image]

If you've scrolled down longer than screen height, the list will be dropped out entirely.

SE App 1.3.2 / iOS 8.4 / iPad Air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

I had copied code from somewhere else when I made that view splittable in landscape, `self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds`, which made the table view take up the whole size of the parent view.  Except in this case `self.tableView == self.view` so the table view shrunk to its visible bounds cutting off however much had been scrolled.